# How to use a class variable inside the declaration of a member function in Python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a class which is declared somewhat like:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

I need to pass the member variable object "a" as a default argument for a member function of this class, something like:

```
    def foo(self, x = self.a, y = -1):
        if (y == -1):
            bar()
        else:
            some_function(x)
```

But this is results in error "self is not defined" at self.a, and that is understandable.

Basically, if x is equal to a, y = -1, which will cause "bar" to be executed, and save me from checking the value of x in the other part. This is, of course, a simpler version of the program, but is similar in essence. Checking if x = a will be long, since x is a complex object in itself. Do I have any easy way out of this, like anyway to pass the member object as a default argument, or will I have to write a function to compare the two objects?

This question may come across as dumb, or the code as being badly written, but I am just an inexperienced hobbyist, and I don't know a lot. I am just learning to make programs more complex than "Hello World!" in Python-3.

Comment: `x=None` and `if not x: x = self.a`?

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik , this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. There's no `self` when you're defining the class and its methods, so you can't use an attribute as a default.

The general idiom when you want the default to be calculated dynamically is that you put the calculation in the function itself, and use `None` as the default value.

```
def foo(self, x = None, y = -1):
    if (y == -1):
        bar()
    else:
        if x is None:
            x = self.a
        some_function(x)
```

This will work as long as `None` is not a possible normal value of the parameter.

Comment: If you want to be able to use `None` as a normal value of the parameter, you can declare a constant like `_DEFAULT_X = object()`; then you're guaranteed it's specifically that one when you go `if x is _DEFAULT_X`. On the other hand, it makes it harder to write wrapper functions, because those need to have the same default (or two code paths so as not to pass `x` when not wanted).